# Help understand syntax of this statement in C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on DevExpress Report, and I see this kind of syntax everywhere. I wonder what are they? What are they used for? I meant the one within the square bracket `[]`. What do we call it in C#?

```
[XRDesigner("Rapattoni.ControlLibrary.SFEAmenitiesCtrlTableDesigner," + "Rapattoni.ControlLibrary")] // what is this?
    public class SFEAmenitiesCtrl : XRTable
```

Comment: It's awfully hard to look up something when you don't know it's name, isn't it?

Comment: @DOK: Exactly, I thought I knew C# well, but then when I saw this kind of syntax, it threw me off :(.

Comment: This always tickles me: when discussing attributes, you don't say that you "add" an attribute. You say that you "decorated" the class with the attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are called [Attributes](http://www.dotnetperls.com/attribute).

Attributes can be used to add metadata to your code that can be accessed later via Reflection or, in the case of [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/5307/aspect-oriented-programming-using-net/3/), Attributes can actually modify the execution of code.

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` syntax above a type or member is called an attribute specification.  It allows a developer to apply / associate an attribute with the particular type or member.

It's covered in section 24.2 of the C# language spec

- http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/24.2.htm

Answer (score 1):

They are called [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). They are quite useful for providing metadata about the class (data about the data).

Answer (score 1):

It is called an attribute.

In this case, DevExpress is using **custom attributes** on their report classes.

If you're interested in why you want to create custom attributes, [this article explains it](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-the-advantages-of-custom-attributes-in-your-c-applications/6175490).

Answer (score 1):

They are called [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288059%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), You can use them to mark classes, methods or properties with some meta-data that you can find by [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) at runtime.

For instance, one common one is [**Serializable**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which marks a class as suitable for conversion into an offline form for storage later.

Answer (score 0):

Piling on to the previous answers, this is an attribute that takes a string value in its constructor.  In this case, the '+' in the middle is a little confusing... it should also work correctly with:

```
[XRDesigner("Rapattoni.ControlLibrary.SFEAmenitiesCtrlTableDesigner,Rapattoni.ControlLibrary")]
```